# Static Variables in WebApplication/WebMethods

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have web method as following

```
static FileTypeData DataLine = null; 
static string FilePath = ""; 
static string MarketName = string.Empty; 
static string FileType = string.Empty; 

[WebMethod]
public static string GetData (string MarketName, string Category, string Symbol)
{
    MarketName = MarketName.ToLower(); 
    FileType = ""; 
    Category = Category.ToLower(); 
    Symbol = SymbolToLower(); 
    return Start();
}
```

`MarketName`, `FileType`, `Category` and `Symbol` are `private static` variables.
The problem is when leaving `GetData` web method and move to `Start` method these variables are reset to their initial values, that means they are empty. I want to know why this behavior exists.

Note: I call this web method by ajax request.

Comment: Pro tip: Post code as text, and turn it into a code block. See the button **`{}`** in the Question Editor.

Comment: Please type your code inside your question

Comment: Don't use static variables in this way. Pass the variables to `Start()`, or you're going to have problems when more than one system calls this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameters of your method have the same names as you static variables, the parameters will be used. So assigning a value to `MarketName` will change the value of your **parameter**, not of your **variable**!

To change this, you have to add the name of the class in front of the variable name:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData (string MarketName, string Category, string Symbol)
{
    MyClassName.MarketName = MarketName.ToLower(); 
    // ...
}
```

**Important:** If you want to use these values inside of `Start()` you should pass these parameters instead of using static variables!

Comment: thanks its working fine with me.

Comment: @PulsarMist it works fine while testing with one browser, but as soon as multiple users use this API, it's going to cause trouble. Read the duplicate.